# Is there an English expression for a day off for bridging the gap to the weekend?

Tags: expressions, translation

Coming Thursday (Ascension day) will be a holiday, and I'd like to take the day off on Friday. Like this I'd like to bridge the gap towards the weekend.

In Dutch, this is called "making the bridge", is there an English word/expression for (taking) such a day off?

Comment: We never get Thursdays as holidays, so the situation doesn't arise.  The exception being Christmas Day, where the Friday would also be a holiday anyway.  The nearest expression is probably *Poet's Day*.  (Push Off Early Tomorrow's Saturday)

Comment: @Chenmunka 'Push off', eh? Never heard that version…

Comment: In Turkish, we "connect" holidays to weekends.

Comment: @Chenmunka we get a similar situation if Christmas day falls on a Tuesday or Wednesday (in the UK). Boxing day can be a Thursday. Other English-speaking countries don't pin their holidays to the weekend (isn't Thanksgiving a Thursday?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted the "bridge" is not a common in Britain so the expression you may use is:

> - to take the extra [day off](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/day+off) (between 2 public holidays)

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idiom)

Comment: What a pity there is no nice name for such a nice day :-)

Comment: @Dominique - it does exit in other languages as far as I know, Spanish, Italian and Portuguese.

Comment: @Dominique Think of the Japanese. In late-April/early-May there are 3 or 4 national holidays over about an eight-day period. As a result some employers give a whole week as a holiday. It is known as [Golden week](http://web-japan.org/kidsweb/explore/calendar/april/goldenweek.html)

Answer (score 1):

Another way of referring to the desire for the Friday off between a Thursday holiday and a weekend is "desiring a 4-day weekend."

Comment: I would say *making (it into) a 4-day weekend*.